# ant not working:The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: ant

A couple of days ago i fixed a blue screen problem i had on my laptop following the directions from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlnjT2iSCpk)
.Since then, i cant run apache ant tool.As for my system variables:

1)ANT_HOME---->C:\Ant\apache-ant-1.8.3

2)JAVA_HOME--->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

3)PATH-------->%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin

When i type ant in the command shell, the output is "the syntax of the command is incorrect".
I'm working on windows vista operating system..
Have you any ideas what is happening? Does it has to do with the blue screen problem i fixed?
Please help me..

Comment: The output is the same again:"the syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: Actually the problem is solved..This was happening because my CLASSPATH system variable was ending with "."

Comment: Great, good to know you resolved the issue.